# iPad Safari Event Handler

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, dom-events

Let's say I have a box/table with multiple rows.. These rows are draggable.

Now I have a JS where I have implemented event handlers for touchstart,touchmove, touchend for the iPad....Basically they just map these events to corresponding mouse events like mouseover, mousedown, mouseup, etc

Now here is my issue;

While I am able to drag any of the rows from the table, I also want to be able to scroll it. When I press any finger on screen and drag down, it does the drag action for that row (since I am using `event.preventDefault()` for touchmove to prevent the default scrolling region).

Now I understand that I cannot have both the actions (drag/scroll) using a single finger..
So I want to implement/have a scroll action when 2-fingers are used.. (The other case i.e. for single finger, it should do the drag action)

Now I am aware that `event.touches.length`/`event.targetTouches.length` gives no of fingers on screen, I am not sure how to use that to do the scrolling action... Just as an FYI, this scrolling would be similar to what we get on the iPad for fixed height div scrolling (`overflow:auto`), which iPad provides out-of-the-box..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fire preventDefault *later*, and optionally. 
Figuring out if you want the custom / drag behavior first.

something like this: ( i have no idea if this exact code will work since i cannot test it right now, this assumes you use jQuery, and i don't know the event properties for the number of fingers but just to give you an idea:)

```
$('#SomeElement').TouchMove(
   function(e)
     {
        if( /* number of fingers equals one */ )
        { 
          e.preventDefault()
          //more element-drag code could go here
          return;
        }
     }
);
```

Comment: Thx for your reply...However what I want is that if no. of fingers is more than 1, the entire view should scroll like what we get on finger-scroll...

Comment: which means you need to prevent/stop the default event if the number of fingers is just one, right?
i'm a little confused -_o

Comment: *or* you could just put the items in their own scrolling frame, which would enable the two-finger scrolling requirement by default, but that might cause problems with your item-dragging behavior.

Comment: All i want is to scroll the entire page when there are 2 fingers on screen...similar to what u would get with 1 finger...

Comment: And like i said in the previous comment, one of the ways to do that is with a fixed-height scrolling element.
If you're not even going to *try* these things and just downvote the answer, then fine, but give me a heads-up so i won't put in the effort anymore